# How does 1 left shift by 31 (1 << 31) work to get maximum int value? Here are my thoughts and some explanations I found online

Tags: bit-manipulation, max, bit, twos-complement

I'm fairly new to bit manipulation and I'm trying to figure out how (1 << 31) - 1 works.

First I know that 1 << 31 is

```
1000000000000000000000000000
```

and I know it's actually complement of minimum int value, but when I tried to figure out (1 << 31) - 1, I found an explanation states that, it's just

```
10000000000000000000000000000000 - 1 = 01111111111111111111111111111111
```

I was almost tempted to believe it since it's really straightforward. But is this what really happening? If it's not, why it happens to be right?

My original thought was that, the real process should be: the two's complement of -1 is

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

then (1 << 31) - 1 =

```
(1)01111111111111111111111111111111
```

the leftmost 1 is abandoned, then we have maximum value of int.

I'm really confused about which one is right.

Answer (score 9):

It's both! 1 << 31 is:

```
1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Subtracting 1 gives:

```
0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

One of the nice features about the two's complement layout of signed numbers is that addition and subtraction are exactly the same operations as they are for *unsigned* numbers. So 10000...000 represents a negative number in two's complement, the largest negative number, which is -2,147,483,648 in this case, and subtracting 1 from it causes wrap-around to the largest positive number, 2,147,483,647, but two's complement numbers are arranged so that we can pretend it's an *unsigned* number instead, so the subtraction is uncomplicated. Subtracting 1 from 10000...000 simply drops the leading 1 to a 0, and borrows a bunch of 1s, same as in decimal you get a bunch of 9s: 10000 - 1 = 9999.

It's also true that mathematically, `(a - b)` is the same as `(a + (-b))`, so we can do `(1 << 31) + (-1)` instead:

```
  1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000    (1 << 31)
  1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    (-1)
-----------------------------------------
1 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    +

  0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111    (truncate)
```

A 1 is carried out of the high end, and lost once the result is truncated back into a 32-bit integer.

Either way, that pattern, with a single 0 at the high end, then filled by 1s, is the representation of the maximum positive value for a two's complement integer of any width.

There are other ways to generate that pattern if you prefer, such as `~(1 << 31)`, and `(-1 >>> 1)` (where `>>>` means [logical shift right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)) which is agnostic of the width of the integer.

Comment: `a - b = a + (-b)` is always true in theory, it's just that programming languages are picky about which constants they accept - works fine if `a` and `b` are variables.

Comment: @harold I was about to argue, but you're right. It turns out that for `b = -2147483648` (or whatever corresponding value for the int size), even though the true value of `-b` cannot be represented and it evaluates equal to `b`, it doesn't matter because overflow means that `a + b = a - b`, a surprising edge case I'd never realized. I guess it makes sense when thinking about the bit representation of -2147483648, which is 1000....0000, so regardless of whether you add or subtract, or even xor, the only effect it can have on `a` is to flip its uppermost bit.