# Manually adding a bitmask vs adding a bitwise shift

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am trying to add in a left-wise operator to replace the following:

```
unsigned long bitmask = 0b10000000000000000000000000000000;
printf("%lu\n", bitmask);

unsigned long bitmask2 = (1 << 31)-1;
printf("%lu\n", bitmask2);
```

However, the closest I'm able to get is `-1`. If I try doing (1 << 31), it looks like I get an overflow or something. What would be the proper way to do this?

```
# in the python shell
>>> 0b10000000000000000000000000000000
2147483648

>>> 1<<31
2147483648

>>> 0b10000000000000000000000000000000 == 1<<31
True
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating maximum int value in C program (1 << 31) - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019187/calculating-maximum-int-value-in-c-program-1-31-1)

Comment: [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714), [How does 1 left shift by 31 (1 << 31) work to get maximum int value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39206842/995714), [Is unsigned long int correct for this operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35119136/995714), [C++ bitwise left shift by 32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40951434/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All integer constants like `1` have a type, in this case `int`. An `int` is signed and therefore has 31 data bits and 1 sign bit. You cannot left shift data into this sign bit - `1<<31` is a severe undefined behavior bug.

As a rule of thumb, never mix signed operands with bitwise operators. You can fix the bug by adding a 'u' suffix to the integer constant: `1u << 31`. Now the type is `unsigned int` instead, 32 data bits.

Please note that the resulting type of a shift operation is that of the *left* operand. So there is no need to write for example `1u << 31u`.

Comment: There seems to be quite some incorrect information: 1. in C/C++ `int` is not necessary to be 32-bit  2. as the variable is `unsigned long`, it is a better idea to make sure the result type of the shift operation is also `unsigned long`.  That's why in other answers, we are suggesting `1UL` instead of `1U`. 3. I believe the resulting type is determined by the `left operand`.  For binary operators, it should be determined by type promotion, for which will promote to `unsigned long` if either side is `unsigned long`. Which means, it will also work to write `1 << 31UL` (though looks funny)

Comment: @AdrianShum In case `int` isn't 32 bits, then the OP's question doesn't make any sense, now does it? `unsigned long` is irrelevant, because it is either 32 or 64 bits and in either case it doesn't affect the shift operation the slightest. Using `ul` instead of `u` doesn't add anything except fussiness.

Comment: @AdrianShum Your understanding of type promotion for the `<<` operator is incorrect and `1 << 31UL` will _not_ work but invoke undefined behavior. As mentioned in the answer, the shift operators are a special case and the usual arithmetic conversions do not apply. Instead, both operands are integer promoted and the result is the type of the promoted left operand, always. I would appreciate if you don't downvote my answer because _you_ don't understand how type promotion works.

Comment: @AdrianShum To spell it out to you, C17 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators **"The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
that of the promoted left operand."**

Comment: 1. you are right that on OP's platform, `int` is 32 bit, there is no doubt.  What I meant inaccurate is the statement `An int is signed and therefore has 31 data bits and 1 sign bit.`.  imho it is overly simplified to say `int` has certain width.  It could be better to say "on your platform".  2. it is totally possible to `unsigned int` with 16 bit (though not on OP's platform).  Only `long` is guaranteed to be 32 bit or wider.

Comment: 3. You are right, I misunderstood the standard here :) I mistakenly though it is doing type promotion, but turned out it is just integer promotion.  Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 3):

Since the type of the result of your shift is `unsigned long`, you should start with an unsigned long constant:

```
unsigned long bitmask2 = (1UL << 31) - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
unsigned long bitmask2 = (1 << 31)-1;
```

to something like

```
unsigned long bitmask2 = (1UL << 31);
```

instead

The overflow was caused by you are bitwise shifting 31 places for `1` which exceed the boundary of a signed int.  Please note that `1` is a signed int literal.